# R-Markdown ggplot grid not showing correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, r-markdown, knitr

I knitted my Markdown file to pdf today, and noticed something strange in regards to the displaying of the grid lines of ggplot().

This is how my grid lines look like in SumatraPDF:
[Correct grid lines in SumatraPDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQh2e.png)

And this is how they look like in AcrobatReader:
[Incorrect Grid lines in AcrobatReader or Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru8xc.png)

this is the how I set up the grid:

```
panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#f9f9f9", size = 2)
```

Acrobat and edge seem to scale the grid size as a function of document zoom and to use the color 'grey' for both the grid and the vertical line at Wednesday, while they should in fact be of different colors and fixes size as shown in SumatraPDF. Even if I set the grid size to 100 in element_line(), the grid lines are always around 1 pixel thick in the final pdf when displayed in Acrobat reader or edge, regardless of zoom.

Does anyone have an idea why this is and whether there is a workaround?

this is my header and setup:

```
---
title: "xyz"
author: "xyz"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Comment: Or maybe just keep a thin grid - looks better (see for example https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/balance-data-context.html). The thick grey grid makes a weird optical effect

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. I setup the Rmd file as you indicate, took the first example in `?geom_point()` and added `+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#f9f9f9", size = 2))`. I tried viewing the PDF with Edge, Chrome, Adobe Acrobat and everywhere it just looks like a wide line that scales with zooming. Nowhere did it look like a 1 pixel wide line.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting. I restarted R, knitted again and the issue was resolved. Should have tried that from the start.